# Keyboard Stopped working after upgradeto 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, keyboard, acpi

As stated in the title, my keyboard stopped working after upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04.

The keyboard works in GRUB and in recovery mode.

I already checked all the accessibility options.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

but it didn't change anything.

I don't know if this is related but I have a Nvidia GTX950M but I don't see it in the "details" section of the settings, instead I see a "Intel HD Graphics 530(skylake GT2). 
So I also tried different Nvidia drivers but it didn't change anything either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing that my keyboard was not detected in /proc/bus/input/devices in normal mode but was detected in recovery mode, I looked at the GRUB config file and remembered as I saw it that I had to add the option acpi=noirq for my booting to work well in 16.04. 
Removing acpi=noirq resolved my issue.
So if you're having similar issues on a laptop, you can try to look at ACPI debugging.